# Save multiple records based on user input in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, multiple-records

**What I'm using:**
cakephp version 2.4.1

**What I have:**

table **channel_settings** with attributes (id, mask_id, provider_id, servicetype_id, channel_id, created, modified)

table **channel_alert_defaults** with attributes (id, provider_id, servicetype_id, channel_id)

In page add new channel_setting user can insert each provider to each servicetype to it's channel.

Now what I need is when user choose servicetype to --Any-- then besides this one record, there will be some multiple insert into database for some servicetype because some servicetype need different channel. Amount of multiple insert depent on how many a provider has servicetype setting and channel in table **channel_alert_defaults**

**Here's existing system:**
[image: existing condition]

**What I want now:**
[image]

Here's what I'm trying, but I still don't get any idea how multiple insert code is

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        Controller::loadModel('Servicetype');
        $this->Servicetype->recursive = -1; 
        $servicetype = $this->Servicetype->find('all');
        $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'] = $this->Session->read('current_mask_id');
                    $maskid = $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'];
                    $providerid = $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['provider_id'];
                    $servicetypeid = $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['servicetype_id'];

        $this->ChannelSetting->create();

                    if ($this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['servicetype_id'] == 0) {

                        Controller::loadModel('ChannelAlertDefaults');
                        $this->ChannelAlertDefault->recursive = -1; 
                        $channelalertdefault = $this->ChannelAlertDefaults->findByProviderId($providerid);
                        // loop insert goes here, I think...

                        if ($this->ChannelSetting->save($this->request->data)) {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting has been saved'), 'success');
                                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                        }
                        else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting failed to save'));
                        }

                    } else {
                        if ($this->ChannelSetting->save($this->request->data)) {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting has been saved'), 'success');
                                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                        }
                        else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting failed to save'));
                        }
                    }

                        if ($this->ChannelSetting->save($this->request->data)) {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting has been saved'), 'success');
                                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                        }
                        else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The channel setting failed to save'));
                        }
    }
```

}

PS: why I want this? So that I don't have to insert data one by one for each provider. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't test now but maybe you can try something like this:

```
$data = array(
                [0] => array(
                        'MASK' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'],
                        'PROVIDER' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['provider_id'],
                        'SERVICE_TYPE' => *all*
                ),
                [1] => array(
                        'MASK' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'],
                        'PROVIDER' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['provider_id'],
                        'SERVICE_TYPE' => *otp*
                ),
                [2] => array(
                        'MASK' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'],
                        'PROVIDER' => $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['provider_id'],
                        'SERVICE_TYPE' => *httpalert*
                )
        );

        $this->ChannelSetting->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Javi thank you for give me inspiration on how I should solve the problem.

What I've done:
1. count how many data from table channel_alert_defaults than correspondent to provider_id from user input
2. Make a loop insert into table channel_setting using saveAll

Here is my code:

```
Controller::loadModel('ChannelAlertDefault');
                        $this->ChannelAlertDefault->recursive = 1;  
                        $channelalertdefault = $this->ChannelAlertDefault->findAllByProviderId($providerid);
                        $amount = count($channelalertdefault); // to count how many array
                        // Here is the loop...                           
                        if ($this->ChannelSetting->save($this->request->data)) {
                            for($i=0;$i<$amount;$i++) {
                                $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['mask_id'] = $this->Session->read('current_mask_id');
                                $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['provider_id'] = $channelalertdefault[$i]['ChannelAlertDefault']['provider_id'];
                                $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['servicetype_id'] = $channelalertdefault[$i]['ChannelAlertDefault']['servicetype_id'];
                                $this->request->data['ChannelSetting']['channel_id'] = $channelalertdefault[$i]['ChannelAlertDefault']['channel_id'];
                                $this->ChannelSetting->saveAll($this->request->data);
                            }
```

Comment: loop isn't necessary to save multiple rows to same model at once. Just use saveAll one time, or loop with save :)